# how to transfer dictionary value into a tuple?

Tags: python-3.x

could anyone help me with tranforming dictionary values into a tuple please.
The dictionary:

```
dic = {'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
```

and im looking to get output only values as tuple:

```
tup = (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Did you try `tuple(dic.values())`?

Answer (score 0):

Just access the dict values, then make it a tuple:

dic = tuple(dic.values())